# Get messages from telegram channel I am admin of channel

Tags: node.js, express, axios, fetch, telegram-bot

I want to get all messages from the telegram group. My bot is one of the admins of this group. The bot has access to get messages via TelegramApi getUpdates. Now I am faced with one problem.
When I use from browser `https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/getUpdates?chat_id={}`, I respond to all messages, that's ok. However, when I want to use the same link getUpdates from nodeJs via fetch or Axios, I respond only `[]`.
If I stop nodejs server, then refresh this browser page `https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/getUpdates?chat_id={}`, after starting the server, I get a response with data. How can I get a response with all data without refreshing the browser page and server nodejs?

```
const https = require('https');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express')
const sequelize = require('./db')
const Messages = require('./models')
const request = require('request');
const axios = require('axios');

const token = ''

const bot = new TelegramApi(token, {polling: true})

const app = express()
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
)
app.use(express.json())

const saveData = async() =>{
    //await sequelize.authenticate()
    //await sequelize.sync()

    const base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/{}/getUpdates?chat_id={}"

    const get = await app.get(base_url)

    await fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/getUpdates?chat_id={}')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log("First user in the array:");
        console.log(json.result);
    })
 }

saveData()
```

Comment: When do you want to see the response?

Comment: @hoangdv twice a day

Comment: :-? Change `saveData()` to `setInterval(saveData, 60*1000)`, then you can see the response for each minute, in the terminal.